# Java, how to properly implement nested iterators on Lists?

Tags: java, performance, list, nested

I have two java `List<String>` objects, and I need to add in a third `List<String>` result object all the possibile combinations of the first two ones. Like:

```
List<String> list1 = getList1();
List<String> list2 = getList2();

List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String value1 : list1) {
    for(String value2 : list2) {
        result.add(value1 + value2);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this quick and dirty function becomes exponentially slow when the lists grow:

`long combinations = list1.size() * list2.size()`

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, is there a better approach to it or any framework that can be used?

Comment: You might be able to do better if the lists have many duplicates. Just insert all elements in each `List` to `Set`, and use the same code for iteration. This method will be slightly worse than current method if duplicate is not common. If you want to find all combinations, you must spend at least as much time complexity as the number of unique combinations.

Comment: In this scenario there are no duplicates.

Comment: I think this method is the most straight forward then. If there are no duplicate in the 2 list, then the only thing that can be done is to avoid recalculating the same combination. However, I can't think of anyway to do that, though.

Comment: Then use a Set! Set<String> allValues=new HashSet<String>(list1); allValues.addAll(list2);

Comment: I can't because I need to do a concatenation between the two values. For example if value1 (belonging to list1) is "one" and value2 (belonging to list2) is "two" the resulting object should be: "onetwo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it faster, you can provide the initial capacity to the result so that the internal array of ArrayList is not extended:

```
int capacity = list1.size() * list2.size();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(capacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you get what you want by calling result.size() instead of multiplying the sizes together?

Answer (score 0):

The slightly-harder-but-definitely-better way is to extend an [unmodifiable `AbstractCollection` (or `AbstractList`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) and the associated iterator (that will iterate on the two `List` iterators as needed). This way you won't need O(N*M) storage for the combined list.